# Dúvida sobre NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Existe alguma forma de fazer algo parecido com o ListView do Android no NetBeans? Preciso fazer uma lista personalizada em um JFrame, como é feito no ListView do Android.

Comment: O NetBeans não é uma linguagem de programação, ele é um IDE onde se pode usar várias linguagens(veja a descrição da tag). Terá de contextualizar melhor o que quer fazer.

Comment: no caso eu queria listar itens em um jframe, de maneira personalizada como em um ListView do Android